# Notepad++ regex find containing str1 and not containining str2

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
1. The CAT goes up and down the ROAD.
2. The CAT goes up and down the CITY.
3. The ROAD goes up and down the CAT.
```

Regex: `(CAT)(.*?)(ROAD)` will find lines containing CAT and ROAD

Now I need to find lines containing CAT and NOT containing ROAD.

Tried `(CAT)(.*?)(?!ROAD)` but that seems to be not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use negative and positive look-ahead together. Positive to detect lines with CAT and negative to negate ROAD.

```
^(?=.*CAT)(?!.*ROAD)(.*)
```

I've also added `.*` at the end to select these lines.

Comment: thanks! how to highlight not the whole line but the "CAT" only?

Comment: If notepad++ had a support for negative look-behind, you could use `(?<!ROAD.*)(CAT)(?!.*ROAD)`. But it doesn't. What is your use-case?

Comment: There is a better answer by Jerry.

Answer (score 2):

To select `CAT` only on lines that don't contain `ROAD`, you can use a negative lookahead and `\K` which resets the match:

```
^(?!.*ROAD).*\KCAT
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dH5jP8)